# transforming form view-port coordinates to real image coordinates

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

i have a big image about :(14848 PX width * 14336 PX height ) i used deep-zoom tool and exported the files to silverlight, and used a 'multi scale image' control.
the multiscaleimage is 400*400 px .
after the projects starts i want when i click on some where in the image to know the 'real' coordinates for the real image not for the width of the multiscale control,considering the panning and the zooming factor...
so if there is a way to know that.i hope you guys help me.
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSDN docs on this are hopeless.  [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/03/31/a-deepzoom-primer-explained-and-coded.aspx) actually defines the terms:

- Logical Coordinates – is a normalized value (0 to 1) representing a coordinate in the image itself (not the control)
- Element Coordinates – is the actual control coordinates. For example in a MultiScaleImage of Width=800, Height =400, when the mouse is at the center, the element coordinates are 400,400.  These coordinates are not normalized.

[I copied that definition from the blog post, but the example seems to be wrong: the element coordinates should be 400,200.]

It's clear then that you want [MultiScaleImage.ElementToLogicalPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.multiscaleimage.elementtologicalpoint%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to convert mouse coordinates to image coordinates.

The image coordinates are in the range [0,1].  Simply multiply by the original image width/height to get pixel coordinates in the original image.